Linux devices can ping ip address but not hostname in local network
I have a network that contains two Linux devices, a router, and a Windows machine. The Linux machines can ping each other using IP addresses and are able to resolve domain names like www.google.com, but they are unable to resolve each other's hostnames.
Output of resolvectl status of linux machine 1
Output of resolvectl status of linux machine 2
The error I am getting is "Temporary failure in name resolution". The 192.168.0.1 is the router ip
Router DHCP settings

This is a Ubuntu Q&A support site, and you only mention Linux (which is supported on Stack Exchange Unix & Linux).  You mention a DHCP Server, but not a DNS server that changes hostnames to actual IP addresses; did you setup a DNS Server?

Domain is required to resolve registered names with systemd-resolved. If you do not have own registered, use home.arpa domain.
But using also 8.8.8.8 offered to machines will not work, not reliably. Only router knows local names, DNS.google doesn't. For them to work only one DNS server should be offered from DHCP - router's address. Common trick to use router's address first will not be reliable with systemd-resolved or any other cache, unless it try name servers in the same order. Only dnsmasq has special option for that AFAIK.
Alternative solution would be using mDNS or LLMNR multicast protocols for local machines resolution, Google servers for internet names.
